# Django development server serving css but not js

Tags: python, django

I am developing a django (1.4) app on my local machine.  I am running the built-in development server with `python manage.py runserver`.  In base.html I have:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}boostrap-dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

boostrap.css loads just fine when I load a page, but bootstrap-dropdown.js is 404'd.  They are sitting right next to each other in my static directory.  Relevant parts of settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/home/username/projects/projectname/static',)
```

Debug is set to `True`.  I have tried it both with and without the `staticfiles_urlpatterns` trick.

Django can find one file in the directory but not the other?  I think I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"{{ STATIC_URL }}boostrap-dropdown.js"
```

`boostrap` is probably not what you want.
`bootstrap` is probably what you meant.